# m-m relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two tables `Customer` and `Promotion` that have a many-to-many relationship.

I have used EF Core to generate the tables.

The `Customer` table has 3 columns:

- `id`
- `name`
- `address`

The `Promotion` table has 2 columns:

- `id`
- `discount`

I have added 3 customers to `Customer` table and also some data in `Promotion` table.

I want to get list of `Customers` using Linq who are given promotions...

For example, Customers 1 and 2 are given promotions while customer 3 is not give any promotion. So I want to get the list of customers 1 and 2.

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: How is the many-to-many relationship defined? You can't have a many-to-many relationship with only 2 tables: you need to show us the (often hidden) linking-table that matches each `Customer` with a set of `Promotion` rows and vice-versa. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Something like `List<Customer> customersWithPromotions = await dbContext.Customers.Where( c => c.Promotions.Count() > 0 ).ToListAsync();`

Comment: I am using ef version 6. The ef core has generated a third table customerpromotion that has the foreign keys customerId and PromotionId. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: You can get the list in customers (virtual collection) or in the junction table customerpromotion

Comment: C# is a language of types. Instead of showing us the tables, can you show us the types (e.g. classes) created for the tables?

Comment: public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Promotion> Promotion { get; set; }
    }  public class Promotion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @victor, update answer. Can you read this comment? We can't.